# Что значит a%b>0?

Tags: c++

Что значит выражение `a%b>0`, например в таком коде `min= a/b+(a%b>0);`.

Answer (score 6):

Это деление с округлением в большую сторону. Почти эквивалентный код:
This code performs a division with rounding up. Almost the equivalent code:

```
double a = 5;
double b = 2;
int min = std::ceil(a/b);
```

[Example](http://cpp.sh/2qkz)

Answer (score 3):

Что дает в результате код, объяснено в другом ответе. А я попробую объяснить *как* это происходит.

Оператор `%` для двух целых вычисляет остаток от целочисленного деления первого аргумента на второй. Например, `10 % 4` даст `2`. Далее, применение оператора `>` дает логический (булев) результат. Т.е. результат выражения `2 > 0` будет `true`. Когда булево значение используется в арифметическом выражении, `true` преобразуется в `1`, а `false` в `0`. Поэтому `2 > 0` даст `1`.

Ну и в итоге вся цепочка для `a = 10`, `b = 4`:

> `a/b+(a%b>0)` ... `10/4 + (10%4>0)` ... `2 + (2>0)` ... `2 + 1` ... `3`

Вердикт: если значения делятся с остатком, то прибавляется единица (происходит округление в б*о*льшую сторону); если значения делятся без остатка, то прибавляется ноль (т.е. результат уже есть минимальное большее целое).

Ровно тот же результат даст выражение `std::ceil(static_cast<double>(a)/b);`.

Answer (score 3):

Результат зависит от того, какие типы ваших переменных. Я предположу, что ваши переменные целочисленные. Для типов с плавающей запятой смысла практически нет, для пользовательских типов с переопределённым делением и взятием остатка смысл может быть произвольным.

Число `a % b` даёт остаток при делении `a` на `b`. При этом знак остатка зависит от знака *делимого*: если делимое отрицательно, то и остаток будет отрицательным или нулём.

Для случая положительного делимого, рассмотрим два случая.

1. Пусть `a` нацело делится на `b`. Тогда `a/b` даёт частное, `a%b` равно 0, `(a%b > 0)` есть `false`, при сложении будет преобразовано в константу 0, и результат есть просто частное.
2. Пусть `a` не делится нацело на `b`. Тогда `a/b` даёт целую часть частного, округлённую *в сторону нуля*, `a%b` равно положительному остатку, `(a%b > 0)` есть `true`, при сложении будет преобразовано в константу 1.

   а. Для положительного `b` округление в сторону нуля есть округление вниз, то есть результат есть просто **частное, округлённое вверх**.

   b. Для отрицательного `b` округление в сторону нуля есть округление вверх, то есть результат есть **частное, округлённое вверх, и увеличенное на 1**.

Теперь рассмотрим случай отрицательного делимого. В этом случае остаток отрицательный или ноль, `(a%b > 0)` всегда равно `false` и приводится при сложении к нулю, так что результат совпадает с `a/b`, то есть, **частное, округлённое в сторону нуля**.

Иллюстрация: http://ideone.com/WmcyTT.

---

Судя по всему, автор кода не учитывал, что числа бывают и отрицательными. Для положительных `a` и `b` мы получаем всё время частное, округлённое вверх. Для этого, как указано в других ответах, есть специальная функция [`std::ceil`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/ceil), которая работает правильно для всех вариантов знака.